# Changing app.config as part of MSBuild script

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am using an MSBuild build file to build and test my application. As part of the process I would like to change the path and name of the log file (setting in app.config). What is the easiest way to do it (I have the xpath to the value that needs to be changed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at The MSBuild Community Tasks Project at http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/
There's a task called XmlUpdate, which does exactly what you need.